# Missing Admin under app launcher in Sharepoint Office 365

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, integration

I unable to find Admin option in App launcher. I navigate to `https://www.office.com/?auth=1` which opens the Sharepoint page at the left hand i see the App Launcher when i click on show all apps i dont see the admin access. Based on the document i should see the admin option can anyone please help me with this.

`https://sharepointmaven.com/the-anatomy-of-a-sharepoint-url/`

Answer (score 1):

You should navigate to a SharePoint site url like this: `https://yoursite.sharepoint.com` instead of the `https://www.office.com/?auth=1`. Then you could see the admin in the App Laucher.

Besides, you could go to the admin center directly with this url:https://admin.microsoft.com

[image]

Comment: I just configured by Microsoft account using my personal gmail account, i am not sure what does Site name means.
And when i try with the other link ``` https://admin.microsoft.com ```` it is not accepting with gmail account. Cant i get the admin option for gmail account ?

Comment: To access to the admin center, you need to be assigned to admin roles. Guest user cannot be assigned admin roles. So your gmail account cannot get the admin. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/add-users/assign-admin-roles?view=o365-worldwide